# jquery event button showing right response but view is not rendering it correctly in django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I want to show wrong login errors on jquery click.My code is working fine,jquery event(click) button showing response correct too but django views are not rendering the response correctly.In response in inspect element they are showing error as i sending the  context but the change do not display on screen.

login view

```
def logn(req):
    if req.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    
    if req.method == 'POST':
        usrname = req.POST['lusername']
        psswd = req.POST['lpass']
        if len(psswd) == 0:
            print('error')
            context={
                'error_msg':'password?'
                    }
            return render(req,'base.html',context)
        usr = authenticate(req,username=usrname,password=psswd)
        if usr is not None:
             login(req,usr)
             redirect('home')
```

Jquery

```
$('#lbtn').click(function(){
    let lusername = $('input[name=lusername]').val();   
    let lpass = $('input[name=lpassword]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/login/',
        headers :{
            'X-CSRFToken':  getcsrfToken(),
        },
        data: {
            lusername : lusername,
            lpass : lpass,
        },
        success: (data) => {
            if(data){
                $('input[name=lusername]').val('');
                $('input[name=lpassword]').val(''); 
            }
        },

    })  
})
```

HTML

```
<div class='bg'>
          <span><i class='material-icons tiny left cross'>clear</i></span>
          <i class='material-icons tiny right spin'>cached</i>
      {% if error_msg %}<p class='red-text'>{{error_msg}}</p>{% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class='white-text log_title'>
          LOGIN
      </div>
      <div class='white-text log_title1'>
          Please enter your username and password
      </div>
      {% if error_msg %} <p class='red-text'>{{ error_msg }}</p>{% endif %}
      {% csrf_token%}
          <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s9">
              <p for="lusername" class='white-text log_user'>Username</p>
              <input name='lusername' type="text" class="validate white-text" id='in1'>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s9">
              <p for="lpassword" class='white-text log_user'>Password</p>
              <input name='lpassword' type="text" class="validate white-text" id='in1'>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class='center'>
          <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue black-text" type="submit" name="action" id='lbtn'>
              Login
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class='topper'>
          <a href='/'>
          Forgot Password ?
          </a>
      </div>
</div>
```

login modal is in 'base.html'. So,i have to render 'base.html' in different views with different context.

Answer (score 0):

First off, in Line 3 of your HTML `{%endif%}` should be `{% endif %}`

Furthermore, it sounds to me like this condition is not being met: `if len(usrname) == 0 and len(psswd) == 0:`

Verify the length of `usrname` and `psswd` in python...

Comment: okk corrected but still same problem, in jquery event response it shows error but not in template